# How to set the default browser style outline on child when parent is on focus

Tags: html, css

When the parent is on focus, I'd like to show outline on the child instead of the parent. I've this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/JananiA/0zj3bc1g/2/).

```
a {    
   display:inline-block;
   width:300px;
   height:300px;
   outline: 0;
}

a:focus > .b {
   outline: 1; /* can be initial, does not work */
}
```

The outline shows on the child if the style is,

```
a:focus > .b {
   outline: red solid 3px;; 
}
```

How to set the default bowser style outline on the child? I have Chrome, FF and IE9+

I am interested in bringing the **default browser style** for the outline.

Comment: Do you have an structure like this¿ : `<a href="..."><element class="b"></element></a>`. Or have you got this structure?: `<a href="..."><b></b></a>` It's very different! In second, you need to remove the dot in your selector `a:focus > b`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude check fiddle

Comment: I'm sorry, the structure is in the JSFiddle. It is something like `<a href="..."><element class="b"></element></a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't show outline in elements that haven't got outline. That's a border. You remove the outline in the `<a>` tag and this is fine, and then add a border to the `.b` element:

```
 a:focus > .b { border: 1px solid red; }
```

### Edit

Test with active

```
 a > .b:active {
     outline: 1px solid red; 
 }
```

Comment: You could set [outline for a span](https://jsfiddle.net/JananiA/863fd8rg/2/).I dont not want to change the default outline style so that the accessibility is not messed up.

Comment: Yes, but span can't get focused. You must to change to `:active` pseudoclass

Comment: I do not want to style the span when in focus or active. I just want the styling of the focus to apply to the child span instead of the parent when the parent receives focus. I hope i have conveyed my problem.

Comment: I think that you need to found another tag different of `span`. A tag that can be focused. `:active` works on any tags onmousedown, but disappears onmouseup obviously. Tags that can be focused: `a, select, input, textarea, button, area`. I think that I don't missed anything

Comment: Thanks, I will try with a button.

Comment: good luck, tell us if you found the solution with this explanation :)